Undefined name 'CustomTextStyle' when using a custom TextStyle in Flutter
I'm getting the following error:
lib/main.dart:40:54: Error: Undefined name 'CustomTextStyle'.
            const Center(child: Text("Helpy", style: CustomTextStyle.primary)));

when I tried to add a custom text style to my text.
main.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:helpme/custom_widgets.dart/CustomTextStyle.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});
  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        child:
            const Center(child: Text("Helpy", style: CustomTextStyle.primary)));
  }
}

CustomTextStyle.dart
class CustomTextStyle {
  static const TextStyle primary = TextStyle(
    fontSize: 24,
    color: Colors.black38,
    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
  );
}

There are no errors showing before I compile so not sure why its giving me this error?

I have tried with your code and it works perfectly without any error.

Thank you - I restarted VS Code and now it works.
